# Expose custom DateTime property to user control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am developing a calendar where my days are aligned like this

```
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Path=SundayLabel, FallbackValue=Sunday}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DayLabelStyle}" />
    <custom:DayDisplay Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="SundayDisplay" />

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Path=MondayLabel, FallbackValue=Monday}"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DayLabelStyle}" />
    <custom:DayDisplay Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="MondayDisplay" />
```

and so forth. DayDisplay is a custom WPF control.
The control containing all theese DayDisplays needs some way to set the individual days with a DateTime preferably from code behind.

Is there some way to expose a custom property in my DayDisplay view so i could do something like:

```
    <custom:DayDisplay Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="MondayDisplay" x:Day="{MondayDateTime}"/>
```

Preferably i would like to store all custom:DayDisplay pairs in a Dictionary and have them autogenerated also if it is possible. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks,
Niklas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should expose a DateTime dependency property on the control, done like so:

```
    public DateTime Day
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DayProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DayProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Day.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DayProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Day", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DayOfWeek), new UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.MinValue));
```

if you want this to be auto generated, what you should do is have an ItemsControl that contains this dayControl of yours, like so:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="DaysItemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <custom:DayDisplay Day="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

and then DataBind it from code behind:

```
        DateTime[] week = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2000,1,1), new DateTime(200,1,2) };
        DayItemsControl.ItemsSource = week;
```

Comment: This is perfekt. Thank you very much :D One follow question. I want this change to be propagated to my DataContext on my DayView. Is there some way to constrain this by using a OneWay binding? Thanks

Comment: I couldn't understand what it is you want to do, can u explain more in depth? (also, mark question as answered :)

Comment: I have a CalendarView containing a list of DayViews (Thanks to you :D). The CalendarView sets the day of the DayView with a binding like <custom:DayDisplay Day="{Binding}">. Now i want to be able to change this day from CalendarView code behind and have that change trigger an property update on my DayView.DataContext. Like if i have a Property, CurrentDay, in DayViewModel I want this to update when changing the Day DependencyProperty. I guess i could make a new question of this :) Thanks. I will mark this as the answer. I just wanted to wait a bit to see if i got more answers :)